# MeteorJS file in template

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, meteor

I'm working on Meteor app, and we just received a HTML/CSS design, with a custom min.js for a slider, and I would add it in my templates and I don't know how to do it ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add all the required html, javascript and css files in the package.js file api.addFiles section.

```
api.addFiles(['css/file1.css', 'js/file2.js','file3.html'], 'client');
```